# how to include types for bootstrap-table when compiling typescript in an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, npm, bootstrap-table

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 5 app and instead of using JS I want to use TypeScript.

I'm using some JS libraries, so in order for the TS to compile it needs definitions for them.

I've set up NPM with devDependencies of the type definitions for the libraries, which downloads them to node_modules, and the TS compiler finds and uses them.

My NPM `package.json` is:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bootstrap": "5.0.17",
        "@types/jquery": "3.5.6",
        "bootstrap-table": "^1.18.3",
        "jquery": "3.6.0"
    }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "DOM",
            "ES5",
            "ES2015"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "wwwroot/js/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

This works for JQuery and Bootstrap, but it's not working for bootstrap-table.

My project structure is:

```
root
  wwwroot
    js
      home.ts
  views
    home
      index.cshtml      // imports ~/js/home.js
  node_modules          // the folders in here are automatically maintained by NPM
    @types
      bootstrap
      jquery
    bootstrap-table
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

The error when compiling `home.ts` is `(TS) Property 'bootstrapTable' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

I thought the problem might be caused by the type definitions for bootstrap-table being included in the main library, which means it's not in the @types subdirectory of node_modules.

I've tried forcing the TS compiler to see it by manually specifying typeRoots but there are just a lot of compile errors because it starts seeing all sub-folders as modules that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just want to use the bootstrap-table plugin, you can download the plugin directly using the add -client library:
[image]

Or use CDNjs node directly:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-table

Comment: That downloads the library and type definitions, but it doesn't address getting the TS compiler to see the definitions in the library folder